# goto statement vs recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, goto

I am writing a function that opens a file, where open mode depends upon user choice. Given below is the function

```
void open_file(char T)
{
    string name;
open:
    cout << "\n Enter filename/path : ";
    cin >> name;
    if(T == 'N')
        file.open(name);
    else 
        if(T == 'O')
        {
            file.open(name, ios::app | ios::in);
            if(!file)
            {
                cout << "\n File not found. Try again";
                goto open;
            }
            file.seekg(0);
        }
}
```

if the file is not found, the program goes to `open:`, for that I have used the unappreciated `goto` statement. Please note that `open:` starts after the declaration of `name`.

I want to know if `goto open` is less memory efficient / slower than `open_file('O')` or not, since `open_file('O')` will declare `name` every time it is called.
Please note: The only reason people give for not using `goto` statements is that they make the program more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to read if you would have used a `while` block instead of `goto`. No need for recursion.

```
void open_file(char T)
{
    string name;
    bool retry;
    do {    
        retry = false;
        cout << "\n Enter filename/path : ";
        cin >> name;
        if(T == 'N')
            file.open(name);
        else 
            if(T == 'O')
            {
                file.open(name, ios::app | ios::in);
                if(!file)
                {
                    cout << "\n File not found. Try again";
                    retry = true;
                } 
                else
                    file.seekg(0);
            }
    } while (retry);
}
```

Comment: you mean `while(file){ // ...}` ?

Comment: You did not define file in your question, so I've defined a boolean the checks if the open succeeded.

Comment: nice catch, but it was a member function of a class that has an fstream. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @gromit190 using `goto` in your code makes it tougher to read and understand so eliminating it results in easier to read code

Comment: @gromit: Try drawing an NSD for a `goto` and you will see. A `goto` is only then **not** spaghetti if you use it exactly like you would `while` / `for` / `switch`...